# Transistor to switch low voltages (< 1V)

Tags: mosfet, bjt, low-voltage

I am building a system for pulsed electrodeposition, where I would like to switch very low voltages (0.3 - 1.0V.) I am not sure about the type of transistor to use for that. A BJT would drop 0.7V, so there wouldn't be any voltage at the end. A MOSFET would also have a high resistance at this voltage, if I am right.

How can I switch very low voltages?

EDIT: Current and timings will not be critical (1-100 mA, pulse durations above 1 ms range.)

Comment: "*A MOSFET would also have a high resistance at this voltage, if I am right.*" Wrong. The gate-source voltage used to switch is not the same as the voltage being passed across the source-drain. Also true for the BJT: 0.7V is the base-emitter voltage, not collector-emitter.

Comment: Saturate a BJT and it can drop 0.2V or less (C-E), sometimes down to about 50mV at low currents.

Comment: When you say “pulsed”, what’s the timing like? Would a relay suffice or are the pulses too short/ fast?

Comment: You could use e.g. solid state relays. They have no problem switching very low voltages and the control is isolated.

Comment: Electrodeposition? I have red (probably bullshit) that it could be a way to 3D print handguns which do not explode on user's face. Explode or not, any in human scale practical size piece of metal dissolved & extracted through liquid would need either substantial electric current or very long time. With 1A you dissolve&extract only few grams per hour. Could you instead of using a switch control a switch mode power supply which outputs the wanted maybe pulsed low voltage or even regulates the current?

Comment: I am actually working on a metal 3D printer with that technology. The idea is not to print the full metal part, but lay down wires which will be fused by electrodepositing metal into the contact points. There are specifically recipes made by the chip industry to fill trenches in wafers which can hopefully adapted. Also hot ferric chloride baths can plate up to 3 um per second, so you can make a 1 cm thick part in 1 hour. As for handguns: That is not allowed in the EU and very strictly regulated. People won't print guns, because getting caught means prison.

Comment: But people capable to write proper answers probably want to know the current. Maybe you want to give that data to them.

Comment: Sorry, I amended by question.

Answer (score 2):

A MOSFET is easier to use than a BJT in this case, although a BJT would work.

You can just use a MOSFET (be aware there is a diode between drain and source -- be sure you use the appropriate orientation), and drive the gate with a signal (Arduino ?) to > 5 V to turn on. You have to actively drive to 0 to turn off, or put a resistor (10 k Ω) between gate and source -- when you disconnect the driver, the FET will then be turned off by the resistor.

Comment: So I was erring about how transistors work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Search for low voltage drop DC solid state relays and MOSFETs  with a few milliohm ON resistance (with high enough Vgs). There are types developed for automotive or other high current applications. Solid state relays which are intended for mains AC operated applications are useless for low voltage DC.

A guess: You must also have a way to to produce the low DC voltage and maybe have there some current limitation. Consider also to check if you could control the DC supply instead switching its load.